# Jsfiddle's new UI broke my angular and javascript fiddles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

My jsfiddle that was using angular broke with their new UI updated. Can anyone please tell me why it's not working or what it's missing? I am very confused about this.

```
var shopItems = angular.module('shopItems', []);
var trophyEarns = angular.module('trophyEarns', []);
var app = angular.module('app', ['shopItems', 'trophyEarns']);

shopItems.controller('shopItemController', function($scope) {
  $scope.shopItems = [{
    //id: 01,
    name: 'One',
    //img: '',
    price: '$3.99',
    altprice: '1 mile',
    desc: 'This is a fake description.',
    prog: '50%'
  }, {
    //id: 02,
    name: 'Two',
    //img: '',
    price: '$3.99',
    altprice: '1 mile',
    desc: 'This is a fake description.',
    prog: '50%'
  }];

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/rfg80gye/32/

Comment: Are you saying that *existing fiddles that used to work* broke? That would mean they lost the fact that you'd previously chosen one of the "no wrap" options. If that's the case, you'll want to report it as a bug, it won't just be angular fiddles that break.

Comment: Your initialization code is running in a "load" handler. Change the setting to "No wrap (in body)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's that business of jsFiddle defaulting to the mind-bogglingly-surprising "wrap all of the code in a giant `window.onload = function () { ... };` wrapper" setting.

Just click the word JavaScript and select "No wrap - in <body>" (or "No wrap - in <head>") in the "Load Type" field:

[image]

jsFiddle has always had that setting, and `onLoad` has always (well, at least for several years) been the default for it. It's just moved in the new UI.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfg80gye/33/